# What's the Best WYSIWYG contenteditable plugin for editing HTML while preserving dynamic PHP/ASP/etc. content?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I'm looking for a contenteditable wysiwyg plugin to put on a web page that lets users edit content with the least amount of unnecessary changes to the manually edited html code, similar to dreamweaver.  Most of the ones I find alter the code too much.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is possible. However, another method is to let the user [change any < div >](http://www.nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=3) on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've used TinyMCE on a number of projects and find that it's worked extremely well as a WYSIWYG editor on sites where I need to provide content management and editing functionality to my clients.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/